# Creating dynamic header and footer files

Tags: headers, footer

I have an external search engine and I need to create a page to add it to my site.

The page will sit on an external server, on an external URL.

They are copying in the HTML header and footer but they have the capability to include dynamic files so I would like to do that.

I want to be able to access `header.php` and just print the header HTML and `footer.php` and just print the footer HTML and then they can include these files in their page.

They have sent me instructions but are asking me to separate `meta`, `header` and `footer` files. Also, do I then upload the required PHP files in the root directory or in the theme files?

[Instructions image](https://p4.zdusercontent.com/attachment/258086/NeIGGj0wdBmfNLL4sBLHeMiuF?token=eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMTI4Q0JDLUhTMjU2In0..hBfwzGjuRSeZNmTpNCohIg.PlUPJ8MsvR_whxaUSCd_vjhTqvYN_SnmbWhwuZiSfR2xDJxEqsI3RPyxV22ybnpNHo_cBaqxvtzkNEXhIi9awxlphWlKw_x169rqePS8DYKmr-CUpyW9fUXQyvFrvPDk8g-tDCK9X3-ZjNhqDc6YazOCSRrsfFB9jSeIXDui3_bQk7q3EILlQNkDljlkFlb3KVEHpRifOMH6r7fKBs1weIRe0Rn5ySnJ3LIdB2_bG5e4hzHwISJi0GiMypnnh4QLPhTnXcPqepSGq66FoZkfyA.ktJoPjbSbQJ1M15XAzAkvg)

Comment: Is this related to WordPress, if so what have you done so far and where you are stuck?